# Beautiful Soup Email Protected

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Hello i try to get email information from this code

```
 <a href="mailto:CONTACT@domain.COM">CONTACT@domain.COM</a><br><h3> Description </h3>
```

And my code is

```
text = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
            def get_textchunk(word1, word2, text):
                if not (word1 in text and word2 in text): return ''
                return text.split(word1)[-1].split(word2)[0]
                ## can refine with more conditions/string-manipulations/regex/etc

           
            mail  = get_textchunk('Mail :', 'Description', soup.get_text(' '))
            print (mail)
```

But i print me [Email Protected]

How can i work to bypass this obstacle  ?

Thnk you :)

Comment: Can you provide reproducible example? soup variable is not defined there. Your mail example does not have "Mail :" string, hence get_chunk is always returns  ''

Comment: Sure thanks to find an extended code

<br>Site : <a href="http://www.########.com/">http://www.########.com/</a><br>Mail : <a href="mailto:CONTACT@########">CONTACT@########</a><br><h3> Description </h3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## bs4 solution

you can use bs4 to parse the tree for you

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


sample = ' <a href="mailto:CONTACT@domain.COM">CONTACT@domain.COM</a><br><h3> Description </h3>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "lxml")

print(soup.a.contents)
```

Out

```
['CONTACT@domain.COM']
```

(note: this returns a list object)

And if you're looking at a large tree:

```py
for a in soup.find_all("a"):
    print(a.contents)  # same result
```

## regex solution

*disclaimer, you shouldn't really use regex to parse html, that being said:

```py
sample = ' <a href="mailto:CONTACT@domain.COM">CONTACT@domain.COM</a><br><h3> Description </h3>'

pattern = re.compile(r"href\s*?\=\s*?\"mailto\:(?P<email>[^\"]+?)\"")

print(pattern.search(sample)["email"])
```

Out:

```
CONTACT@domain.COM
```

for many:

```py
for matched in pattern.finditer(sample):
    print(matched["email"])  # same result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email from the mailto: directly

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="mailto:CONTACT@domain.COM">CONTACT@domain.COM</a><br><h3> Description </h3>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
email_link = soup.find('a', href=True)

# Extract email address from the mailto link
email = email_link['href'][7:]  # Remove the 'mailto:' part

print(email)
```

Comment: How will this help with the "[Email Protected]" issue OP is asking about? Please make sure your answers actually address the question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: @Chris I use OP's code to produce a result which doesn't have an Email Protected issue. If OP is experiencing an issue then his question is not full and thee issue not reproducible. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](How to Ask)

Comment: If this worked, OP wouldn't have asked about "[Email Protected]". If you can't reproduce (or understand) a question, the best thing to do is to ask for clarification, as mardadian did above, not to answer.